# Dynamically Select Options From Multiple Select Dropdown With Reactstrap In React js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jquery-select2, reactstrap

I have the following function:

```
loadTag(data, td) {
    var tag = this.state.session.tag.map((el) => 
    $.inArray( el.name, data ) ? 
    <option key={el.name} value={el.key} defaultValue>{el.name}</option> : 
    <option key={el.name} value={el.key}>{el.name}</option>);
    ReactDOM.render(
      <Input type="select" className="dropselect_tag" name="tag" multiple>
        {tag}
      </Input>,
      td);
}
```

I want to be able to dynamically select mulitple options within the list of options provided into my select drop down. For my select drop down i'm using `reactstrap` and `select2` plugins and it does initialize but with nothing selected.

I have tried this also:

```
loadTag(data, td) {
    var tag = this.state.session.tag.map((el) => 
    <option key={el.name} value={el.key}>{el.name}</option>);
    ReactDOM.render(
      <Input type="select" className="dropselect_tag" defaultValue={data} name="tag" multiple>
        {tag}
      </Input>,
      td);
}
```

But it doesn't produce any result. And I am very sure that i'm sending in a array like this `["item"]`. I parse my array from my db and test like so:

```
 data = JSON.parse(data.replace(/&quot;/g,'"'));
 console.log(typeof data); 
 console.log(data);
```

Is there a way that i can pull this stuff out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve it this way:

```
loadTag(data, td) {
  data = JSON.parse(data.replace(/&quot;/g,'"'));
  var tag = this.state.session.tag.map((el) => <option key={el.index} value={el.index}>{el.index}</option>);
  ReactDOM.render(
      <Input type="select" multiple={true} defaultValue={data} className="dropselect_tag" name="tag">
        {tag}
      </Input>,
      td);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

My advice is to use react-select, It is able to select mulitple elegantly. Can you give it a try?

`npm install react-select`

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Select from 'react-select'

const options = [
  { value: 'chocolate', label: 'Chocolate' },
  { value: 'strawberry', label: 'Strawberry' },
  { value: 'vanilla', label: 'Vanilla' }
]

const MyComponent = () => (
  <Select options={options} />
)
```

[react-select docs](https://react-select.com/home)

Comment: thanks, i'm this works also. but i was able to resolve it